# Pending approval requests for design-patterns topic documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

The documentation requests for design-patterns topic has been in approval stage for more than a week.

From the badge stats, bronze badge has been awarded only 69 times till now => you can find less silver badge and less bronze badge experts.

It would be great if approval process for these topics are fast tracked by reducing the auto accept criteria from Silver to Bronze badge.

Any thoughts on these lines?

Comment: The tag might not need a documentation area at all. Why would you show design patterns separate from the language they're for? Sure, there's some general ideas that are used by all, but i'd wager that the majority of [tag:design-patterns] tagged questions are also tagged some primary language where these patterns are likely already discussed anyway. The top question was also tagged javascript, which has that documented already.

Comment: Those questions lack real world code examples. Most of the websites documented simple theoretical examples.

Comment: @Ravindrababu Personally, I think they should be simple theoretical examples. We shouldn't be writing entire tutorials for people on design patterns. They should be able to read it in the abstract form and apply it to their situation. That's kind of the point of design patterns.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree.

If a tag has such low activity, I don't see the point in adding it as a documentation topic.

The topic would require some people that are regularly active in the tag to maintain it. Preferably, more than a handful of users.

Also, this specific tag is just way too broad for documentation. You'd be better off having a design patterns topic for each tag.

Comment: Tag have mediium activity. The people who got bronze badge are less compared to other tags. If you see top questions in design-patterns, you can see the popularity. http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=design-patterns. Some question/answers have 7K up-votes

Comment: @Ravindrababu [I don't see any 7K+ votes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns?sort=votes) A better metric for popularity is looking at the [newest queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) and see how often good questions come through there. Based on my incredibly unscientific assessment, there's a good question every day or two. That's not very high activity.

Comment: I have modified the query: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=design-patterns%20is%3aQ. Some questions have crossed  350000 views. New questions per day are around 15-20 .

Comment: Only _one_ question has that many views. The next one below it has something like 260k views.